# Clean URLs and php extension on nginx

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite

I've looked at dozens of other questions and references on the web - and by all my calculations, my setup should work, but it doesn't.

I have nginx installation with php-fpm.  If I try to access a .php file, it runs correctly and I get the correct results.  I got this in my config file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Now, I want to setup my web app so that `/somedir/file` automatically executes `/somdir/file.php` while still displaying `/somdir/file` in the browser's address bar.  So I modified my config to contain the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?query_string
}
```

This *kind of* works, that is, the server does access the .php file.  Yet, instead of executing it using the existing `location ~ \.php$` block above, it simply spits the php source code as the download into the browser.  If I append the .php manually to the requested URL, then the php is executed.

It feels as if once the server matches `try_files` to `$uri.php`, it then does not do another pass at locations to see that what it needs to do with the php files.  I tried putting the php block above and below the `location /`, but it makes no difference.

How can I get the php to be executed?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try with the `rewrite` directive? For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
} 

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Source: http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url

Answer (score 3):

`try_files` always executes in current context, that's why it serves your *php*-scripts as plain files - current location lacks `fastcgi_pass`. `try_files` is evil because instead of straightforwardness it creates questionable blocks, avoid it.

In the same time *regexp*-locations have priority over ordinary locations, that's why nothing changes when you reverse the order.

Personally I think that hiding `.php` extensions from address bar is useless, as it adds more code to the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  php extension is not hidden for security - these are API calls used by a number of external applications that I don't control.  API used to be written in something else and later rewritten in php.  I am in no position to require developers of all external systems that communicate with my api to change their code to new urls.  Hence I need to get this working.  What should I change in my config?

Comment: Add `fastcgi_pass` etc on the same level as first `try_files`.